# Can't save the value "change"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Why I can't save the value of change(label). It only saves 0.00 in the database. The 0.00 value is came from the form_load. The addTransaction() sub, it contains a code that save/insert the transnumber, date, time, month, day, and year and for the addTransactionLog() sub, it contains a code that save/insert the total, cash, and change in the database.

It's working except on the change. What should I do?

```
Private Sub btnOkay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOkay.Click
    btnOkay.Text = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to proceed the transaction?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If btnOkay.Text = DialogResult.Yes Then
        btnOkay.Text = "OKAY"
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In frmPOS.ProductsListDGV.Rows
            productCodes = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            itemdesc = dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString
            quantityrow = dr.Cells(2).Value.ToString
            sizerow = dr.Cells(4).Value.ToString
            updateQuantity()
            addStockOutTransaction()
        Next
        addTransaction()
        addTransactionLog()
        btnOkay.Text = "OKAY"
        Me.Close()
        frmPOS.lblTenderedValue.Text = accumulatedpayment.ToString("#,##0.00")
        frmPOS.lblChangeValue.Text = change.ToString("#,##0.00")
        MsgBox("Transaction has been completed.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
     End If
End Sub

Public Sub addTransactionLog()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbltransaction_logs(employee_number, trans_total, trans_cash, trans_change, trans_number) VALUES(@employee_number, @trans_total, @trans_cash, @trans_change, @trans_number);"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = insert_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@employee_number", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = frmPOS.txtEmployeeID.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_total", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = frmPOS.lblTotalAmountValue.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_cash", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = frmPayment.txtAccumulated.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_change", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = frmPOS.lblChangeValue.Text})
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@trans_number", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = frmPOS.txtTransactionID.Text})
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of `change` when you do this: `change.ToString("#,##0.00")` ? If you test with a hard-coded value for the `@trans_change` parameter does it work?

Comment: What is frmPOS? Is it an instance of some form class or is the class name of a form named frmPOS? By the way, you are calling the insert code before changing the label.

Comment: You should set `Option Strict On`.  `DialogResult` and `String` are 2 very different types.  If you researching the capabilities of the DBProvider objects you'd discover none of that code is needed because they will do it all for you.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks guys! Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: As a lover of VB I would not discourage verbosity and I would never discourage the use of parameters in any form but just to save you a few keystrokes     .Parameters.Add( "@employee_number", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar) .Value = frmPOS.txtEmployeeID.Text